# Navigationbar white tintcolor looks gray

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am developing an application which supports iOS 7 and later, using navigationbar with bartintcolor of "green color". However, I got a problem when setting "tintcolor" to white. It became gray color instead of white (as shown in the image below).

Thanks,

[image: NavigationBar]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and spent lots of time figuring it out.

1. Go to iOS Settings > General > Accessibility > Increase Contrast.
2. Turn off "Darken Colors" switch.

Comment: Thank you. You save my 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

please add code below to your appdelegate file

```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"FONT_NAME" size:15] }];
```

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor and UITextAttributeFont are all deprecated in iOS 7.

Comment: I use the new suggested attributes: "NSForegroundColorAttributeName" & "NSFontAttributeName", and it seems not working at all.

Comment: if you are adding navigation bar button then you have to add that button as a custom button in navigation bar